# model Search with join 2 DB's YII2

Tags: php, yii2

I need to compare one field from the "original" (DB1 MYSQL) Search, with a table from another database , (DB2 SQL) but i got this error :

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'nexus.reparossigitm' doesn't exist
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `intragovAnalitico`.* FROM `intragov_analitico` LEFT JOIN `REPAROSSIGITM` ON `REPAROSSIGITM`.`IF_TQI_CODIGO` = `TQI_CODIGO`.`TQI_CODIGO`

How can i do leftjoin with this 2 models ?

My Model 1

```
class intragovAnaliticoSearch extends intragovAnalitico
{   
  [...] 

    public function search($params)
    {   
 // THAT'S OK IF I DOESNT NEED TO COMPARE WITH ANOTHER DB FIELD >

        //$query = intragovAnalitico::find()->where(['IF_POI_NOME' => 'Reativo','PL_OPERACAO_PACOTE' => 'INTRAGOV','AL_TIPO_ALARME' => 'DISP']);

// A TRY >
        $query = intragovAnalitico::find()
                    ->select('intragovAnalitico.*')
                    ->leftJoin('REPAROSSIGITM', '`REPAROSSIGITM`.`IF_TQI_CODIGO` = `TQI_CODIGO`.`TQI_CODIGO`')
                    ->where('intragovAnalitico.IF_POI_NOME' => 'Reativo','intragovAnalitico.PL_OPERACAO_PACOTE' => 'INTRAGOV',
                        'intragovAnalitico.AL_TIPO_ALARME' => 'DISP' )
                    ->all();

[...]

}
```

Thanks ^^

Comment: Yii2 Query builder doesn't let you work between databases. You need to use a custom query

Comment: you mean findBySql?

Comment: damn, i forgot that db1 its Mysql and db2 its SQL server X_X

Comment: I meant this: $db = new yii\db\Connection(Yii::$app->db); then $db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll()